# How to focus away from an EditText?

Tags: android

In my application I need to make something happen when an EditText loses its focus. When editing an EditText I can't make it lose its focus. In windows phone there is the this.Focus(); method but here in android it doesn't seem to be the same. How can I do???

Comment: `clearFocus()` and `requestFocus();`

Comment: Thanks! It isn't really what I was looking for but maybe it's impossible in android. This is the closer to what I need. Thanks everybody!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To focus away from Edit Text one should use **clearFocus();**

Now comes if you do need to handle any particular event if the focus is changed then..

```
**use Focus Change listener on view.**


onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
  //Called when the focus state of a view has changed.
if(!hasfocus)
{
//Your piece of code if the focus is lost on text view..
}
```